# php Loop and insert into

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm using a php form with mysql.
I have a loop for and I would like to put the data in the database depends on the column.
For example for data1 -> insert into column1, data2 -> column2

In the loop where i= 1 to 5 I try this

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO day(numb, g['$i']) VALUES('$num', '$tout' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

but it doesn't work. Do you have any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: can you pls show your code for loop?

Comment: Don't use mysql_*! And construct you query rather then looping through and making many connections to the server firstly secondly what error is given

Comment: You are trying to insert two values into the results of a single expression.... what are you trying to accomplish and we can help you out

Comment: first of all correct it g['$i'] to g[$i] now explain what do u want clearly

Comment: As far as I know you can't use an expression as a table name

Comment: What is `g['$i']` this ?

Comment: This is how you safely concat strings: `"INSERT INTO day(numb, " . $g[$i] . ") VALUES('" . $num . "', '" . $tout . "')"` I think the problem here is the quotation..

Comment: @LiamSorsby He's only making 5 calls to the database, looping is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), so would I.
Your query would look like:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO day (numb, $g[$i]) VALUES('".$num."', '".$tout."' )") or die(mysql_error());
```

Just to remind `$con` is the variable used to connect with DB

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to insert in the same row? for now it works but create different rows all the time.

Comment: you want to use only one row for storing ?

Comment: yes one row but different column, the column will change with the index of the loop.

Comment: after inserting a row, adding in again would result in a new row for sure. You have to create a new column each time to insert values in a row but in a columnwise-fashion.

Comment: You have to use an `ALTER` command to add a new column in your loop. `ALTER TABLE day ADD column-name VARCHAR( 255 ) after previous-column-name` Then add the value to this column. Are you getting it ?

Comment: not sure I get it. when do i need to create the alter table after the insert? so my insert will still create a new row?

Comment: No, before inserting. Before inserting add a column using `ALTER` and then insert the your value in that column-name

Comment: Another simple way `ALTER TABLE day ADD new-column-name VARCHAR( 255 ) after previous-column-name` then `UPDATE day SET new-column-name = 'newVal' ` do this sequentially inside a `for` loop. Most likely will solve your case :)

Comment: it works, but the problem is if I run the form again, it say that the column already exist

Comment: `
$fields = mysql_list_fields('database_name', 'table_name');
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {$field_array[] = mysql_field_name($fields, $i);}

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM day");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      if (!in_array($row, $field_array))
     {
       $result = mysql_query('ALTER TABLE day DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS $row;');
     }
}
}
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33890/discussion-between-varun-malhotra-and-user2152947)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'` from around `$i`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO day (numb, $g[$i]) VALUES('$num', '$tout')") or die(mysql_error());
```

MySQL `INSERT INTO` syntax is as follows - `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, ..) VALUES (column1value, column2value, ..)`

Or `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (column1value, column2value, ...)` when you know all of the row names and just insert their values.

First method allows you to insert selected rows where as the second one demands you to insert all of the row values.

You didn't have the dollar sign in front of the array `$g[]`. Also, when using indexes, you don't have to use quotes.

Please, also mind, that `mysql_*` extension is deprecated and not safe, look into [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: you mean `column1, colum2` instead of `row1, row2`

Answer (score 0):

Use this : pressuming `$g` is a variable

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO day(`numb`, `".$g['$i']."`) VALUES('".$num."', '".$tout."' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use below code

mysql_query("INSERT INTO day (numb, $g[$i]) VALUES('{$num}', '{$tout}')") or die(mysql_error());